# mqtt client receives duplicate message from rabbit mq

Tags: duplicates, rabbitmq, mqtt

I use rabbitmq as a mqtt broker, and I have an android pad as mqtt client, and use org.eclipse.paho.client as client sdk. When I send msg from server to pad, I set the retain flag to true. But when I disconnect the pad and reconnect again, it receive not only the latest msg, but also the earlier msg. In my point of view, the mqtt broker should retain the latest one msg, but seems not. On the other hand, when I use acitve mq as mqtt broker, everything is going on well.
Any help will be grateful.

the mqtt client at server end:

```
@Bean("mqttProducerClient")
    public MqttClient mqttProducerClient() throws MqttException {
        MqttConnectOptions conOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();
        conOpt.setCleanSession(true);
        conOpt.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        conOpt.setUserName(routerMqProperties.getMqtt().getUsername());
        conOpt.setPassword(routerMqProperties.getMqtt().getPassword().toCharArray());
        MqttClient mqttClient;
        try {
            mqttClient = new MqttClient(routerMqProperties.getMqtt().getServerURI(), "msg-center-producer-client", new MemoryPersistence());
            mqttClient.connect(conOpt);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            log.error("There is an exception when creating the mqttProducerClient.", e);
            throw e;
        }
        return mqttClient;
    }
```

publish method:

```
 private void publishMsg(String topicName, int qos, Payload payload) {
        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
        message.setQos(qos); //设置优先级
        message.setRetained(LtwBaseConstant.YES);
        String str = LtwFastJsonUtils.parseObjectToJson(payload);
        System.out.println(str);
        message.setPayload(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        sendExecutor.execute(new MqttTask(1, topicName, message));
    }

//MqttTask
 @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                mqttProducerClient.publish(mqttTaskTopic, mqttTaskMessage);
                log.info("publish success, topic: {}, message: {}", mqttTaskTopic, mqttTaskMessage);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                log.error("Mqtt produce message error.", e);
                if (count < MAX_RETRY) {
                    sendExecutor.execute(new MqttTask(this.count + 1, this.mqttTaskTopic, this.mqttTaskMessage));
                }
            }
        }
```

the mqtt client at android end:

```
public class MQTTService {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MQTTService.class);
    private static String topic = "PMT";
    private static MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient;
    private static MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions;
    private static MainActivity activity;

    private MQTTService() {

    }

    public static void start(MainActivity activity) {
        mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
        mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
        mqttConnectOptions.setUserName(SharedPreferencesHelper.getMQTTUsername());
        mqttConnectOptions.setPassword(SharedPreferencesHelper.getMQTTPassword().toCharArray());
        try {
            LOGGER.info("begin to connect mqtt");
            mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions);
            /*mqttAndroidClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, activity, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    LOGGER.info("connect success");
                    subscribeTopic();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    LOGGER.error("mqtt connect failed: {}", exception);
                }
            });*/
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void subscribeTopic() {
        try {
            mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(getDownstreamTopic(), 1, activity, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    LOGGER.debug("subscribed succeed :{}", getDownstreamTopic());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    LOGGER.warn("subscribed failed", exception);
                }
            });

        } catch (MqttException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("subscribe failed", e);
        }
    }


    public static void create(MainActivity activity) {
        MQTTService.activity = activity;
        //create mqtt
        LOGGER.info("MQTT: {}", SharedPreferencesHelper.getMQTConnectionString());
        mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(activity.getApplicationContext(), SharedPreferencesHelper.getMQTConnectionString(), SystemHelper.getVehicleNumber());
        mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new CallbackImpl());
    }

    private static void processPayload(String topic, MqttMessage message) {
        if(!topic.equals(getDownstreamTopic())){
            LOGGER.info("ilegall topic: {}", message);
            return ;
        }
        try {
            Payload payload= JsonHelper.toObject(Payload.class, message.getPayload());
            LOGGER.debug("{}", JsonHelper.jsonStringfy(payload));
            if(payload instanceof TaskPayload){
                TaskPayload casted = (TaskPayload)payload;
                TaskPayload ongoing=SharedPreferencesHelper.getTaskPayload();
                if(!ongoing.getTaskDetailId().equals(casted.getTaskDetailId())){
                    SharedPreferencesHelper.clearTaskState();//only clear when change task, same task can modify tags when driving
                }
                SharedPreferencesHelper.storeTaskPayload(casted);
                MainActivity.getInstance().refreshTaskUI(2000);//TODO shall be listener model
                TaskACKPayload ack=new TaskACKPayload();
                ack.setUserData(casted.getTaskDetailId());
                MQTTService.publishMessage(JsonHelper.jsonStringfy(ack));
                SoundPoolHelper.play(R.raw.new_task);
                MainActivity.getInstance().show();//TODO shall be listener model
                return ;
            }
            else if(payload instanceof TagFeedbackPayload){
                TagFeedbackPayload feedbackPayload = (TagFeedbackPayload)payload;
                DatabaseService.markTagUploaded(feedbackPayload.getTagIdList());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.debug("mqtt subscriber error", e);
        }
    }

    public static void pause(MainActivity activity) {
    }

    public static void stop(MainActivity activity) {

    }

    private static String getUpstreamTopic() {
        return topic + "-upstream";
    }

    private static String getDownstreamTopic() {
        return topic + "-downstream-" + SystemHelper.getVehicleNumber();
    }

    /**
     * publish message as MQTTModel, this will store to sqlite3 if publish failure
     * @param model
     */
    public static void publishMessage(final MQTTModel model) {
        publishMessage(model.getPayload(), new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                LOGGER.debug("publish succeed!");
                CacheDatabaseHelper.markMQTTModelUploaded(model);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                LOGGER.debug("publish failed {}", exception+"");
                model.setUploadFlag(model.getUploadFlag()+1);
                CacheDatabaseHelper.insertMQTTModel(model);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void publishMessage(final String payload) {
        publishMessage(payload, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override

            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                LOGGER.debug("publish succeed!");
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                LOGGER.debug("publish failed {}", exception+"");
            }
        });
    }

    public static void publishMessage(String payload, IMqttActionListener listener){
        LOGGER.debug(payload);
        try {
            if (!mqttAndroidClient.isConnected()) {
                LOGGER.info("reconnect MQTT server");
                mqttAndroidClient.connect();
            }

            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage();
            message.setRetained(true);
            message.setPayload(payload.getBytes());
            message.setQos(1);
            mqttAndroidClient.publish(getUpstreamTopic(), message, activity, listener);
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            LOGGER.debug("mqtt publish exception:", e);
        }
    }

    private static class CallbackImpl implements MqttCallbackExtended {

        @Override
        public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {
            LOGGER.info("connectComplete");
            subscribeTopic();
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            processPayload(topic, message);
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
            LOGGER.info("msg delivered {} to topic {}", token.getTopics(), token.getMessageId());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? What is QOS setting and what is the reconnection setting? Are you resubscribing when you reconnect?

Comment: code is shown above, the qos is 1, when reconnected, I will subscribe topic

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes in connect complete

```
private static class CallbackImpl implements MqttCallbackExtended {

    @Override
    public void connectComplete(boolean reconnect, String serverURI) {
        LOGGER.info("connectComplete. Reconnect : {}", reconnect);
        if(reconnect == false)
        {
            subscribeTopic();
        }
        
    }
}
```

What is happening is that you are resubscribing to the topic on every reconnect.
If you have not closed the connection or unsubscribed from the topic manually, a subscription entry remains in the broker. When you reconnect automatically you again subscribe causing duplicate subscription entry in the broker.

Comment: The v3.1.1 MQTT spec states "If a Server receives a SUBSCRIBE Packet containing a Topic Filter that is identical to an existing Subscription’s Topic Filter then it MUST completely replace that existing Subscription with a new Subscription" so the behaviour you describe appears at odds with that. I'm not saying that RabbitMQ does not do this (I don't use it), but just wondering if you have a link to any documentation covering what appears to be a deviation from the spec?.

Comment: @Brits I'm commenting based on my personal experience. I'd faced the same issue couple of years back.

Comment: I tried as you said above, it still receives earlier message.

Comment: And when I force quit the app and restart it, the log shows the reconnect is false

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the point the not on the mqtt. my rabbitmq has three brokers, and a proxy of mq is used to interact with client, which means any request from client will be dispatched to one of the brokers. And once the broker connected doesn't contain the lasted mqtt message, the above phenomenon occurs.